# Aws s3 trigger lambda on new files that are NOT temporary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i want to launch a lambda for any new complete file, the process is quite simple:

1. i upload files to s3
2. for every new files in the directory I launch a lambda

unfortunately, i see that my lambdas invokes on _temporary/* files, which are files that are not fully uploaded to s3. what can i do?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not fully uploaded"? Where do these temporary files come from? What are they used for?

Comment: we are uploading the files using write function in Spark job process. during the upload the file is kind of "in the process of uploading" and it be under _temporary folder in S3.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a "partially uploaded" file in Amazon S3. Either the whole object is created, or the object is *not* created. Nor does Amazon S3 have a concept of "temporary" or `_temporary/` files. If they exist, it is because your application is uploading those files.

When creating an Amazon S3 event, you can specify a **Prefix**. The event will only be triggered for objects matching that prefix.

Alternatively, you could add a line of code at the start of the AWS Lambda function that checks the Key of the object and exits if it does not need to perform any actions on the object.

Comment: we upload the files to specifix folder and put a trigger on it,for example:
dirA/

during the uploading we see in dirA path and new directory, dirA/_temporary/file_name
when the upload is finished we see dirA/file_name.

our trigger raise two time, one for each file.

as for the trigger, the prefix is the same so we cannot catch it there and uploading a lambda just to filtter our those files seems not optimal, unfortunatlly, currently this is what we do.

Comment: The `_temporary/` path is coming from _your_ activities. It is not a feature/function of Amazon S3.